# How to force the root domain over https without a 301 redirection?

Tags: 301-redirect, https, http

**My Goal:**
My goal is for new users who have never visited my page, and who are unlikely to explicitly type `https://` in front of my-domain.com to land on the `https://my-domain.com` with a response code of 200 instead of landing on the `http://my-domain.com` first, and then be 301 redirected to the `https://my-domain.com` version, which is also cached.

**My situation:**
I am undergoing an attempt to optimize all the WordPress sites I am the manager of. Many of those have the Really Simple SSL plugin installed and activated, mostly for addressing mixed content issues. I decided to uninstall the plugin on two of them, after reading an article ([link](https://servebolt.com/articles/these-plugins-slow-down-your-wordpress/)) on potential performance decreases caused by it, which I wanted to put to the test. Apart from fixing mixed content, this plugin is also responsible for introducing a PHP or .htaccess 301 redirection. Since I was on Apache, and now LSWS, I had the .htaccess one enabled.

**What I've tried so far:**
I started by deactivating the plugin, and temporarily reverting to http to erase all of the plugin's marks. I then deleted the plugin completely from the installation. That resulted in the home_URL and site_URL conversion to http, which I manually edited to https once again. Then ran a DB search/replace for every `http://` instance to become an `https://` one

Next I had the cPanel checked under Domains, where I enabled the Force HTTPS option there, and had the SSL status checked to verify there were no issues there (everything was green). I checked the .htaccess file to exclude the presence of any 301 remnants, and had the cache purged just in case. I did all of the above for both installations individually.

After all of that I visited URL my-domain-1.com and my-domain-2.com from a new chrome incognito session. I noticed that my-domain-1.com loads under `https://` with a 200 response code, while my-domain-2.com still loads under `http://` at first, and is then being redirected to `https://`, which has left me confused.

What should I have done differently, or what is it that I have been missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user types in a website URL without explicitly typing `https`, most web browsers will initially attempt to connect over `http` (though as Patrick mentioned, this is beginning to change - see [Chrome](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/a-safer-default-for-navigation-https.html) and [Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2020/11/17/firefox-83-introduces-https-only-mode/)).

Currently, the only way to communicate to web browsers to never attempt to load your website over `http`, even the very first time they ever load your site, is to submit your domain for [HSTS preload list inclusion](https://hstspreload.org/).<sup>[1]</sup> The HSTS preload list is a list of websites that gets hard-coded into Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, etc. that tells the browsers not to load your website over `http`, even when the browser is freshly downloaded and knows nothing else about your website at all.

I am not sure HSTS preloading is strictly necessary or offers much benefit in your setup (it won't offer any performance benefit after the initial connection compared to non-preloaded HSTS, since HSTS gets cached whether or not it is preloaded), but it is the only answer to your very specific question as asked. In other words, HSTS preloading is the only way to force `https` for first-time visitors who type your domain into their address bar without explicitly typing the `https`, aside from issuing a redirect over an initial `http` connection.

<sup>[1] Some entire TLDs are already on the HSTS preload list, such as `.dev`, but if your website's TLD were on that list, then you wouldn't be seeing this issue with it.</sup>

Comment: "When a user types in a website URL without explicitly typing https, most web browsers will initially attempt to connect over http." This is less and less true and will be reversed in the future. See https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/a-safer-default-for-navigation-https.html "Starting in version 90, Chrome’s address bar will use https:// by default," and https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2020/11/17/firefox-83-introduces-https-only-mode/ (for now has to be setup as a preference)

Comment: "The only way to communicate to web browsers to never attempt to load your website over https" There is another very easy way: don't listen on port 80 (used for HTTP). Any new website starting now should just stop bothering with HTTP and just use HTTPS (port 443). Even if some browsers attempt port 80 they won't get any result hence ensuring nothing is leaked.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the info. I added a note about the new browser behavior. What do you mean by "ensuring nothing is leaked?"

Comment: If you do only HTTPS from the get go, you ensure to have never a plain text communication, so no content appear in the clear anywhere.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek If you don't mind me asking, what's the benefit of that compared to issuing only redirects and no other content on the HTTP port?

Comment: There could be multiple answers to this, but it is akin to IPv4/IPv6. Things changed. If the web was invented today, it would be HTTPS immediately, no one would ever bother to consider a. "plain text" version of it. So since HTTPS is the clear present/future, why keep maintaining old stuff? Doing redirects might be fine but you need to remember doing them, they create problems for POST content (imagine a form), etc. If you start a website fresh, give only `https://` links around and search engines will also only index that + browsers will default/are already defaulting to that.

Comment: But redirects "work" for those absolutely wanting to keep port 80 open for connections, so YMMV. Of course for a real website existing already today it might not be wise to plug off HTTP, but for anything new starting fresh I personnally see no point in having HTTP still around. Sadely not the same can be said yet for IPv6 vs IPv4, even if it should.